# Update settings and refresh PCManFM using command line?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, lxde, pcmanfm

When I changes settings under **PCManFM > Edit > Preferences > Volume Management** using GUI, it immediately reflects the changes.

But my requirement is to do such thing from command line. So am doing things as follow to disable ***mount_removable***.

```
sed -i -e 's/mount_removable=1/mount_removable=0/g' /home/user1/.config/pcmanfm/lubuntu/pcmanfm.conf
```

But It works only after reboot or after I restart the display manager service. I don't wanna do any of this instead I am trying to find a way out such that once I change the **pcmanfm.conf** file I restart some service (or some process) and it will reflect changes on system and under GUI without rebooting or restarting display manager.

I am stuck here, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Mistakes are the proof that you are trying*" - (unknown)

Yes, I made a silly mistake and that too when I knew everything in back off my mind. My colleague pointed out to me and I am like "Oh No!! How did I missed that ??". Anyway.

The solution here is given by following the two steps below.

1) After changing the settings (using **sed** command) kill the PCManFM process.

```
killall pcmanfm
```

2) Restart the PCManFM process.

```
pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu --display :0 &
```

Donot forget to restart it as background process (see the & in the above commnad).